# How to append 2 different jsons to the same prime-ui datatable

Tags: json, datatables, prime-ui

How to append 2 jsons to the same datatable, like:

```
$('#divInWhichTableIsRendered').puidatatable({ 
                  columns: [  
                      {field:'f1', headerText: 'f1', sortable:true},  
                      {field:'f2', headerText: 'f2', sortable:true}, 
                      {field:'f3', headerText: 'f3', sortable:true}, 
                      {field:'f4', headerText: 'f4', sortable:true},
                      {field:'f5', headerText: 'f5', sortable:true} 
                  ],  
                  datasource: ourJson1,
              });

$('#divInWhichTableIsRendered').puidatatable({ 
                  columns: [  
                      {field:'f1', headerText: 'f1', sortable:true},  
                      {field:'f2', headerText: 'f2', sortable:true}, 
                      {field:'f3', headerText: 'f3', sortable:true}, 
                      {field:'f4', headerText: 'f4', sortable:true},
                      {field:'f5', headerText: 'f5', sortable:true} 
                  ],  
                  datasource: ourJson2,
              });
```

Currently if we do so, the table is populated with ourJson2 & the ourJson1 is over written - which is what we DON'T want.

In fact, I have to highlight some specific rows, based on a certain condition (depends on the Json data), but i am unable to do so. If I apply class to the column..then it gets applied to every row.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**
As there is no 'addOption' for `puidatatable` you'll need to **merge** the two datasources (`ourJson1` and `ourJson2`) before you initiate the `puidatatable`.

What you are doing right now is to initiate the `puidatatable` twice - once with the `ourJson1` and after that with `ourJson2`. The second `puidatatable` overrides (obviously) the first one.

**Second question** (you should always ask just one question, if you need to ask another one, create a new question)**:**

Provide the code you execute and we'll be able to help you. We don't know what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: I want to highlight certain rows depending on a condition (from the json data ) .  Can we do so ?

Comment: If you have a separate question, ask a new question. The system is simple: Ask 1 question, get 1 answer. Don't put ask 5 question at once, that's confusing if people just answer e.g., 2 of 5.